# red wire, blue wire connections to black and white wire connections

Tags: electrical

I purchased a new ceiling light that has a red and a blue wire.  The wires in my house to connect it to are white and black.  Which wire connects to which.

Comment: Red, blue, and white, or just red and blue?  Where did you get this light fixture from?

Comment: Please clarify. Are there ONLY red and blue from the fixture? Because if so that makes NO sense, even for a European fixture. Could it be brown and blue?

Comment: What kind of fixture is it? Halogen, incandescent, ... what??? What does the socket look like?